# updating a textview from another thread (using firebase FCM kotlin code as the base)

Tags: android, kotlin

I've built the firebase cloud messaging demo from here:

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging

This is all fine and working as expected.

However, I'm new to Kotlin / Android and I'm struggling to understand how to properly update a textView with the incoming message.  I've created a webView (messageTextView) and can successfully update it from the mainActivity class.  However, when I try to access the textView from the MyFirebaseMessagingService (where the messages are received) in MyFirebaseMessagingService.kt, it doesn't work - and AndroidStudio puts findViewbyId in red.  I've tried wrapping the textView code in runOnUiThread but this also pops up in red.  I appreciate this is wrong but I'm not sure how it is meant to work (conceptually), and can't find the right instructions (probably because I don't know in what way I'm making coding errors).

The mainActivity is this:

```
package com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm.kotlin

import android.Manifest
import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener
import com.google.firebase.Firebase
import com.google.firebase.messaging.messaging
import com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm.R
import com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val requestPermissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(),
    ) { isGranted: Boolean ->
        if (isGranted) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Notifications permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show()
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "FCM can't post notifications without POST_NOTIFICATIONS permission",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
            ).show()
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            // Create channel to show notifications.
            val channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id)
            val channelName = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_name)
            val notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)
            notificationManager?.createNotificationChannel(
                NotificationChannel(
                    channelId,
                    channelName,
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW,
                ),
            )
        }

        val messageWindow: TextView = findViewById(R.id.messageTextView) as TextView
        messageWindow.text = "hello"
```

and this is the MyFirebaseMessagingService.kt where I'm trying to update the textView:

```
package com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm.kotlin

import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.media.RingtoneManager
import android.os.Build
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import androidx.work.OneTimeWorkRequest
import androidx.work.WorkManager
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage
import com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm.R

class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
     */
    // [START receive_message]
    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        // There are two types of messages data messages and notification messages. Data messages are handled
        // here in onMessageReceived whether the app is in the foreground or background. Data messages are the type
        // traditionally used with GCM. Notification messages are only received here in onMessageReceived when the app
        // is in the foreground. When the app is in the background an automatically generated notification is displayed.
        // When the user taps on the notification they are returned to the app. Messages containing both notification
        // and data payloads are treated as notification messages. The Firebase console always sends notification
        // messages. For more see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options
        // [END_EXCLUDE]

        // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
        // Not getting messages here? See why this may be: 
        Log.d(TAG, "From: ${remoteMessage.from}")

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.data.isNotEmpty()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: ${remoteMessage.data}")

            // Check if data needs to be processed by long running job
            if (isLongRunningJob()) {
                // For long-running tasks (10 seconds or more) use WorkManager.
                scheduleJob()
            } else {
                // Handle message within 10 seconds
                //handleNow()
                val messageWindow: TextView = findViewById(R.id.messageTextView) as TextView
                messageWindow.text = "hello"
            }
        }
```

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: Search about `intent`. You can send an intent to `MainActivity ` when there is a new message. Also you can use broadcasts